# Is there a $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism from the submodule $\lbrace 0,2 \rbrace \leq \mathbb{Z}_4$ into $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: solution-verification, modules

Is there any non-zero $\mathbb{Z}$ module-homomorphism $f:\lbrace 0,2 \rbrace \leq \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Q}$ ?. My guess is **NO** because if such a function exists then $f(\lbrace 0,2 \rbrace)$ would be a submodule of $\mathbb{Q}$ with two elements, contradicting the fact that all submodules of $\mathbb{Q}$ are infinite.

Is this right? I need any help.

One more consultation: Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z} \leq \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}_4$ given by $f(n)=[n]_4$. Can this homomorphism be extended to a homomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}_4$?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating and making more precise my earlier comment: $\mathbb Q$ is *divisible*, so any homomorphic image of it is likewise. $\mathbb Z/4$ is not divisible, so there is no (non-zero) homomorphism of $\mathbb Q$ to it.

Comment: Great. Thanks paul.

Comment: Minor quibble, but that last clause should read no *nonzero* homomorphism, right?

Comment: @AlexWertheim, ah, yes, thx. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

A $\mathbb{Z}$ module homomorphism is an abelian group homomorphism. You must have that $2\phi(2_4)=\phi(2_4)+\phi(2_4)=\phi(0_4)=0_\mathbb{Q}$. Hence $\phi(2_4)=0$

Comment: Ok. This coincides with my claim that the only $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism is the zero homomorphism. 
Excuse me for one more consultation. Is the converse true, i.e., is there a non-zero $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism $A\leq \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}_4$ ?.

Comment: Can you kindly clarify please ? @paulgarrett

Comment: May you please take a look at the example provided in the question above ? @paulgarrett

Comment: Many thanks @mich95